# key value field for content types

Tags: 7, entities

I've got a content type which consists of many (arbitrary number) key/value pairs.

What I'm looking for is a module like [Options Element](http://drupal.org/project/options_element), which I can add to my custom content type. Are there any modules like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Double field](http://drupal.org/project/double_field) may be used as key/value field.

Comment: Great answer. Is there anything similar in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1):

I found [multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) to work better than Double field.